# Payara Server and NetBeans 8.2: Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not support asynchronous operations

Tags: java, maven, servlets, netbeans, payara

I'm working with NetBeans 8.2 - Maven and Payara Server 4.1.2.173 #badassfish (build 24).

Already had developed web services, suddenly began to give this error:
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not support asynchronous operations**

Since I had tried to implement SSL, I thought it was this, so I reinstalled Payara Server without SSL, but I kept showing the same error.

Any idea how to correct this problem.

**Error:**

```
Información:   WSPlazaMallgt was successfully deployed in 2,864 milliseconds.
Información:   Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.14 (-SNAPSHOT 20170628-1326 unable to get svn info) para el contexto ''
Información:   Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
Información:   Loading application __admingui done in 8,018 ms
Advertencia:   Attempt to put servlet request into asynchronous mode has failed. Please check your servlet configuration - all Servlet instances and Servlet filters involved in the request processing must explicitly declare support for asynchronous request processing.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not support asynchronous operations
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:4104)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:4081)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1062)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:464)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.async.AsyncContextDelegateProviderImpl$ExtensionImpl.getAsyncContext(AsyncContextDelegateProviderImpl.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.async.AsyncContextDelegateProviderImpl$ExtensionImpl.suspend(AsyncContextDelegateProviderImpl.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.suspend(ResponseWriter.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.suspend(ServerRuntime.java:910)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:327)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:480)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[com.pmgt.resources.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.pmgt.resources.ApplicationConfig threw exception
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Attempt to suspend a connection of an asynchronous request failed in the underlying container.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:328)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:480)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Add the web.xml file, and these settings, but follow the same error.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PlazaMallgt</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.ferbeth.pmgt</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PlazaMallgt</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Code of the class AplicationConfig**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.pmgt.resources;


import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 *
 * @author lgutierrez
 */
@ApplicationPath("/root")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    public ApplicationConfig(){}

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(com.pmgt.common.exceptionHandling.DataNotFoundException.class);
        resources.add(com.pmgt.common.exceptionHandling.DataNotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(com.pmgt.resources.pmgtCCResource.class);
        resources.add(com.pmgt.resources.pmgtEmpresaResoure.class);
        resources.add(com.pmgt.resources.pmgtLocalResource.class);
    }
}
```

**Class code pmgtCCResource**

```
package com.pmgt.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ManagedAsync;
import com.pmgt.services.pmgtCCService;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author lgutierrez
 */
@Path("cc")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class pmgtCCResource {

    public pmgtCCResource(){}

    private final pmgtCCService CCService = new pmgtCCService();

    /**
     *
     * @param asyncResponse
     */
    @Path("GetallCC")
    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    public void getallCatalogoCC(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(ar -> ar.resume(
                Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out")
                        .build()));
        String result = CCService.getallCatalogoCC();
        asyncResponse.resume(result);
    }

    @Path("GetbyIdCC")
    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    public void getbyidCC(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
            @DefaultValue("-1") @QueryParam("IdCC") String IdCC) {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(ar -> ar.resume(
                Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out")
                        .build()));
        String result = CCService.getbyidCC(IdCC);
        asyncResponse.resume(result);
    }
    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Contacto CC">
    @Path("GetallContactoCC")
    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    public void getallContactoCCJson(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(ar -> ar.resume(
                Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out")
                        .build()));
        String result = CCService.getallContactoCC();
        asyncResponse.resume(result);
    }

    @Path("GetByIdCCcontacto")
    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    public void getbyidCCContactoCCJson(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
            @QueryParam("IdCC") String IdCC) {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(ar -> ar.resume(
                Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out")
                        .build()));
        String result = CCService.getbyidCCContacto(IdCC);
        asyncResponse.resume(result);
    }
    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Direccion CC"> 
    @Path("GetallDireccionCC")
    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    public void getallDireccionCCJson(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(ar -> ar.resume(
                Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out")
                        .build()));
        String result = CCService.getallDireccionCCJson();
        asyncResponse.resume(result);

    }

    @Path("GetbyidCCdireccion")
    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    public void getbyidCCDireccionJson(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
            @QueryParam("IdCC") String IdCC) {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(ar -> ar.resume(
                Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out")
                        .build()));
        String result = CCService.getbyidCCDireccionJson(IdCC);
        asyncResponse.resume(result);
    }
    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Eventos CC"> 
    @Path("getbyidCCevento")
    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    public void getbyidCCEventoJson(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
            @QueryParam("IdCC") String IdCC) {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(ar -> ar.resume(
                Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out")
                        .build()));
        String result = CCService.getbyidCCEventoJson(IdCC);
        asyncResponse.resume(result);
    }
    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Imagen CC">
    @Path("getallpathCCimagen")
    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    public void getallpathCCImagen(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
            @QueryParam("IdDestinoImgCC") String IdImagenCC) {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(ar -> ar.resume(
                Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out")
                        .build()));
        String result = CCService.getallpathCCImagen(IdImagenCC);
        asyncResponse.resume(result);
    }

    @Path("getpathbyidCCimagen")
    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    public void getbyidPathCCImagen(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
            @QueryParam("IdCC") String IdCC) {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(ar -> ar.resume(
                Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out")
                        .build()));
        String result = CCService.getbyidPathCCImagen(IdCC);
        asyncResponse.resume(result);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("16x16")
    @Produces("image/png")
    public Response get16x16PNG(@HeaderParam("If-Modified-Since") String modified) {
        return CCService.get16x16PNG(modified);
    }
    // </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: I commented that my headaches started when I tried to implement SSL, a detail I had not noticed that I had enabled **- Netbeans monitor Http -**, after trying many solutions I found a comment that enabled the **- Netbeans HTTP monitor -** and gave conflicts with asynchronous services . ....

** Disable this and problem solved, this cost me several days  ** :-)